# Julia: Why does this function return a value?

Tags: julia

New to Julia, walking through the manual and got to this example under Methods:

```
julia> mytypeof(x::T) where {T} = T
mytypeof (generic function with 1 method)
```

When you call this method with values for `x`, it gives you back the type:

```
julia> mytypeof(1)
Int64

julia> mytypeof(1.0)
Float64
```

My question is: why does this return a value at all? Where, in other words, is the implied return value?

Comment: `= T`. If It was `= 1` the function would return 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should read

```
mytypeof(x::T) where {T} = T
```

As

```
(mytypeof(x::T) where {T}) = T
```

That is, the `= T` is not part of the `where` clause; it's the RHS of the function.

Comment: Makes sense, I misread the syntax, and assumed that the `= T` was part of the `where`.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably my least favourite part of Julia syntax. It's especially problematic, I think, if you omit the braces in `{T}`. Note though that if `= T` were part of the `where` clause, then there wouldn't be any function definition at all.

Answer (score 5):

In Julia, by default, the last value of a function body is automatically returned.

In your case the function body is just `T`. Hence, `T` gets returned. (Think of it actually being `return T`.)

If you don't want to return anything you can `return nothing`.